# Pagination removed from Wordpress website

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am currently implementing a new theme into [my website](https://rnltrading.com).

My current theme is the TwentySeventeen theme however it doesn't fit the purpose of my website.

So I decided to move over to another theme, the TheShop theme. 
***NOTE: THE THEME IS NOT YET IMPLEMENTED***

However, i've ran into a big problem. For some reason the pagination has been removed from my product catalogus page. I've already turned of infinite scroll but this doesn't do anything usefull.

The pagination was there before. This is very confusing to me.

Comment: unless you are using a class to hide the pagination, it wouldn't be css causing this issue. What did you change? Do you have backups?

Comment: I've recently changed hosting provider, however after the move the pagination was still there. Only changes that where made where a few menu items, the footer and some colors for the site. I do have some backups. Would it be any worth changing back to these backups? I would lose the work i've done so far.